# opening a page in same tab in javascript firefox

Tags: javascript, html

guys i tried this `window.open("FirstPage.html", "_self");` and `window.open("FirstPage.html";"_self");` and `window.location.href="FirstPage.html";` to open the second page in same tab but it does nothing ... any help please??
that's how i call it

```
function deleteCookie() {
setCookie("userdata"," ", 1);
setCookie("diff", " ", 1);
window.open('FirstPage.html';'_self');
}
```

and then call the function from onclcik

```
<button type="button" onclick="deleteCookie()">Forget Me</button></td>
```

Comment: are you inside iframe? and how do you execute your js?

Comment: @Teemu i have edited the post .. please have a look :)

Comment: But how do you call the function? From a link? From `onsubmit` handler? From an `area` onclick. All these will prevent `window.location` to  work, `open()` usually fails if a pop-up blocker of the browser is on.

Comment: Instead of `window.location.href="FirstPage.html";` have you tried `window.location="FirstPage.html";`? -----

based on reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location

Comment: @NicholasDaley That's implicitly exactly the same.

Comment: @Teemu You would assume it was the same.  But, given mozilla's developer site mentions assigning to `window.location` but not to `window.location.href`.  I thought there might be a difference in Firefox, even if there wasn't a difference in other browsers.   --- That said, just opened Firefox, and it seems to be happy with either.

Comment: @Teemu i am calling it on  'onclick'

Comment: @NicholasDaley even window.location cant make any change

Comment: `onclick` of what? Please edit the post, and include the exact code which calls this function. @NicholasDaley The documentation of `href` is under [URLUtils](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.href), since it's an inherited property in `location` rather than `window`.

Comment: @Teemu done .. plz have another look

Comment: How about `setCookie`, it's not a native method, and causes an error? Have you taken a look at the console?

Answer (score 0):

`window.open` opens a new window, but using the `_self` parameter, overrides the current page. Doing so stops the execution of the current javascript thread, and the entire first page is now invalid and considered closed.

If you need to have two pages, you cannot use the `_self` parameter, which opens the new page to replace the current one. If you use the `_self` parameter, you will only have one page in the end, and should include the `deleteCookie()` code in the new page.

Another error you had was to have `window.open()` with a `;` inside. The semicolon should be replaced with a comma, as in the first example.

The implementation of `window.location.href` you used should be valid, but for defensive programming, you might want to re-create the URL to pass in the full path of the new HTML file you want to open.

As for your code `onclick="deleteCookie()"`, you may want to replace this with an `addEventListener`, which is a javascript-only implementation. Also, you can try opening the debug panel of most browsers by pressing "F12" on your keyboard and navigating to the javascript console.